# Migrate Neo4j to Cosmos DB Graph database

Tags: neo4j, azure-cosmosdb

What is the easiest way to migrate Neo4j data into Cosmos Graph DB?  Cosmos DB's migration tool doesn't support the Graph/Gremlin API yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,cosmos db migration tool does not support the Graph API indeed. You could commit feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db?category_id=321991) to push the progress of azure cosmos db development.

[image]

As workaround, you could use cosmos db [BulkExecutor](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmosdb-graph-bulkexecutor-dotnet-getting-started) library to transfer data from Neo4j to cosmos db.Please refer to this [source code](https://github.com/syedhassaanahmed/neo-to-cosmos).Here are some disclaimers you need to notice:

1.The app is NOT intended to synchronize a live production database.

2.Node or Relationship property names which are system reserved in Cosmos DB will be prepended with prop_, i.e. id will become prop_id.

3.Because Cosmos DB stores vertices and edges in the same collection, Neo4j Relationship Ids will be appended with edge_ in order to avoid conflicts with Node Ids.

4.This project is NOT officially supported by Microsoft. It is an independent effort, although we really appreciate if you submit PRs to improve it.

Comment: good answer for now.  thank you.  We decided to write our own in Python to get Neo data and insert it into cosmos.  It was a simple solution for our basic need to move the data.